# Best way to store a local database (currently csv)

Tags: ios, sql, swift, sqlite

I have a csv-file with some thousand entries ("name", "country", "city", "population") and I'm wondering what the best way to store this in the application.

It needs to be read only (no need to add, remove, update) and I want to be able to make a query for a coumn (let's say "name") and return the whole line and then store it as an object (NSObject).

Is it possible to convert it to a sqlite db and use a sqlite query?

What would be the best option do you think?

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this you can use Core Data which is the framework apple built for this. There is also Realm which is much easier to setup than Core Data and provides very similar functionality. Those would be your best bets at this time.

Comment: *Core Data* would be overkill for this. Have a look at *[Realm](http://realm.io/)*.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Reading up on it now. Thanks guys!